# Angular 2 Checkbox value with Reactive form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i have checkbox in angular 2 reactive form i need to pass the values of these checkbox in POST api , Right now they will pass value on status.
below are checkbox code it only passed the status like true or false instead of value like 1,2 something like that.

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="servicelatest"  [value]="CatArry[i].id" (change)="serviceCheckBox($event)"/>
```

-------------------**------------------------

```
<div *ngFor="let serviceType of laceDetailFrom.controls.serviceType.controls; let i=index" >
<div  [formGroupName]="i">

<input type="checkbox" formControlName="servicelatest"  [value]="CatArry[i].id" (change)="services[$event.target.getAttribute('value')]=$event.target.checked">&nbsp;{{CatArry[i].cat_name}}
                             </div>
                           </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template Side :

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="servicelatest"  [value]="CatArry[i].id" 
(change)="services[$event.target.getAttribute('value')]=$event.target.checked"/>
```

Component Side :

```
services = {};
```

And then use services as your selected checkboxes values

Comment: Thanks for replay but still not getting proper thing. After post i have still get true and false. i have put same code in html which you put and in component i have take a variable which type is any but problem still remain

Comment: do i need to put services in reactive form group value?

Comment: Will you please share your code , by your code I can expect you have put it in loop

Comment: Hi i have share my loop code please have look on this if anything you want let me known

Comment: services = {}; try with this.

Comment: and console the services on submit.

Comment: Thanks Vivek got the desire result just manipulate some thing in my code as well. Thanks for your time as well

Comment: Will you please upvote and accept my answer ? please.

Comment: You should not be using (change)="..." with reactive forms. Instead you should subscribe to changes.

`this.myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe( data => ..... );`

Comment: @monzonj - any specific reason for that?