# How to assign a checkbox value to Angular form control name?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to assign the check box's value instead of true or false. How can i achieve this?

```
<input formControlName="ota" value="OTA" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: similar question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154299/angular-2-checkbox-value-with-reactive-form

Comment: but that doesnt work. i ' am using formcontrol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a change event to then use `patchValue` (or `setValue`) to assign the `$event.target.value` if it's checked. If not, then assign something else. Here I assign an empty string:

```html
<input formControlName="ota" (change)="$event.target.checked ? 
       otaCtrl.patchValue($event.target.value) : otaCtrl.patchValue('')" 
       value="OTA" type="checkbox">
```

where `otaCtrl` is a variable for your form control:

```ts
otaCtrl: FormControl;

// code...

this.otaCtrl = this.myForm.get('ota') as FormControl;
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejrfpu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Just wanted to add here that I could only get your solution to work for one checkbox. With multiple dynamic checkboxes I had to write a function and sent the event and prop out to it.

Comment: Hi, can you answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889068/reactive-formbuilder-doesnt-accept-form-control-name-from-functions-parameter

Comment: could be helpful, if you can answer this.

Comment: In your example, what is "myForm"? I don't see it declared.

Comment: @AppDreamer Well, OP didn't specify the name of the `FormGroup`, so I used a pseudo name for the formgroup name, i.e `myGroup`. There is a demo attached to my answer, so you can also check that out :)

Comment: may be you can answer my question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429846/loop-through-nested-formgroup-and-change-each-form-control-value-to-null-if-it-h

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work with multiple dynamic built form checkbox elements. So based on that selected answer I did this (assuming the value for a checkbox was a boolean) :

```
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  activeCtrl: FormControl;
  ...
  updateCheckBoxVal(prop, eve) {
    this.activeCtrl = this.form.get(prop.key) as FormControl;
    this.activeCtrl.patchValue(eve.checked);
  }
}
```

The HTML file:

```
<label *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [attr.for]="prop"> {{prop.label}}
        <input  
        [formControlName]="prop.key" 
        [id]="prop.key"
        [type]="prop.type"
        [checked]="prop.value" 
        (change)="updateCheckBoxVal(prop, $event.target);"
        />
      </label>
```

Hope this helps someone, and thanks to @AJT_82 for the inspiration

Comment: may be you can answer my question,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429846/loop-through-nested-formgroup-and-change-each-form-control-value-to-null-if-it-h