# Reactive formbuilder doesn't accept form control name from function's parameter

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a function to create form group like,

```
public initFormGroup(control_name) {
        console.log(control_name) // can log control_name
        return this._formBuilder.group({
            control_name: '' // This control_name is not same as its function property
        });
    }
```

I am passing the control name through the function parameter but the control_name inside this._formBuilder.group is not as that i passed

The result finally looked like ,

```
"children": [
      {
        "control_name": ""
      },
      {
        "control_name": ""
      }
    ]
```

The desired output should be,

```
"children": [
      {
        "programming": ""
      },
      {
        "networking": ""
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation to get the value of your parameter:

```ts
public initFormGroup(control_name) {
    console.log(control_name) // can log control_name
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        [control_name]: '' // now control will have the value of your parameter
    });
}
```